# javascript: adding function to function inside .prototype = {

Tags: javascript

If I add a function in the "constructor", I can extend it with an other function like so:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    this.time = function() { return 4.5; }
    this.time.formatted = function() { return format(this.time(), "HH:mm"); }
}
```

I can't figure out a nice way to do this if I create the function in prototype like so:

```
var MyClass = function() {}
MyClass.prototype = {
    time: function() { return 4.5; },
    time.formatted: function () { ... } // This does not work!
}


MyClass.prototype.time.formatted = function() { ... }
// the line above works but I don't like it since it separates everything.
// e.g. if I have 15 functions inside prototype, the .formatted will be like
// 50 lines apart from the time: function
```

*Edit: * On second thoughts the line above does not work, adding the .formatted messes
the reference to this. Perhaps solvable?

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: The only way to do it is the latter; object literal notation just doesn't support that syntax.

Comment: Why don't you create a second class? An then just do `this.time = new TimeFormatter();`

Comment: This is new approach to Decorator pattern :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the function before creating the prototype object, that allows you to add a property to it, and also gives you the ability to use the function without using `this`:

```
function MyClass() {}

function time() { return 4.5; }
time.formatted = function() { return format(time(), "HH:mm"); }

MyClass.prototype = {
    time: time;
}
```

You can put it in a function expression to keep it together, and avoid having the `time` function in the global scope:

```
function MyClass() {}
MyClass.prototype = (function(){

  function time() { return 4.5; }
  time.formatted = function() { return format(time(), "HH:mm"); }

  return {
    time: time;
  }

})();
```

---

Note: The `formatted` function will be called as a regular function, not as a method of the object. This means that the function `time` doesn't have access to `this` when called from the `formatted` function.

If you need that, you can't have the `time` function in the prototype at all. Each instance of the class needs its own version of the `time` function, where the `formatted` property has access to that specific instance of the object:

```
function MyClass() {

  this.theTime = 4.5;

  this.time = function() { return this.theTime; }

  var t = this;

  this.time.formatted = function() { return format(t.time(), "HH:mm"); }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code does not work:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    this.time = function() { return 4.5; }
    this.time.formatted = function() { return format(this.time(), "HH:mm"); }
}

var m = new MyClass();
console.log(m.time.formatted())
```

Because the `this` inside `.formatted` points to `m.time`, not `m`. You should use:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    this.time = function() { return 4.5; }
    this.time.formatted = function() { return format(this(), "HH:mm"); }
}
```

or

```
var MyClass = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.time = function() { return 4.5; }
    this.time.formatted = function() { return format(self.time(), "HH:mm"); }
}
```

---

Answering your actual question, make a helper function:

```
var callable(f, props) {
    for(p in props) f[p] = props[p];
    return f;
}

MyClass.prototype = {
    time: callable(function() {
        return 4.5;
    }, {
        formatted: function () { return format(this(), "HH:mm"); }
    })
}
```